# how to match a string like hi-hello-yes using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

**solution: (([^-]+-)hello|^hello)(-.+|$)**

I want to use regular expression to match a sentence. The rules are:

- `hello` must in a sentence
- if `-` follow or ahead the `hello`, there must be something before `-` or follow `-`

Exemples of sentences the regexp should match:

```
hi1-hello-hi2
hello
hello-hi1
```

Exemples of sentences the regexp should **not** match:

```
hi1-hihello-hi2
hihello
hellohi
hellohi-hi2
```

I have try `(.*-)?hello(-.*)?` and more, but with no luck.

I use re.match() method
[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this isn't a regex-writing service

Comment: Are you using `re.match()` or `re.search()`?

Comment: It would help to have an example we can reproduce. Can you post the exact command that you have tried and a list or data.frame or dict, containing the strings?

Comment: I use re.search() method

Comment: I have tried but can't figure it out

Comment: I would suggest r"\b(\w+-)?hello-?\b"

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. Just use a word boundary `\b` to match between a word and non-word character and change `*` to `+` inorder to match one or more characters.

```
^(?:.+-)?\bhello\b(?:-.+)?$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iM7vX1/2)

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """hi1-hello-hi2
... hello
... hello-hi1
... hi1-hihello-hi2
... hihello
... hellohi
... hellohi-hi2"""
>>> m = re.findall(r'^(?:.+-)?\bhello\b(?:-.+)?$', s, re.M)
>>> for i in m:
...     print i
... 
hi1-hello-hi2
hello
hello-hi1
```

Comment: Matches "-hello-" and I don't think it should

Comment: @RonRosenfeld just add start and end patterns.

Answer (score 1):

```
^(.+?-)?hello(-.+)?$
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/pP3pN1/34

Comment: Seems to meet all the stated requirements

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful to someone.

```
def hello_match(reg=r"\b(\w+-)?hello-?\b"):
    Eg=["hi1-hello-hi2","hello","hello-hi1","hi1-hihello-hi2","hihello","hellohi","hellohi-hi2"]
    for item in Eg:
        if re.match(reg,item):
            print item

hello_match()
## hi1-hello-hi2
## hello
## hello-hi1
```

Answer (score 0):

`\b(\w+-)?hello(-\w+)?\b`

This improvement DJJ response. His regex grabs the `hello-`